# Test API Python

Tags: python, flask, mock

Como posso testar uma url de uma api, usando o nosetest

por exemplo: tenho a seguinte api: `/api/user`

como garantir que as chamadas nessa url estão sendo chamada?

fazer um `GET`... um `POST` passando os parâmetros no body

Tentei usar o `pyresttest` mas não consegui fazer funcionar muito bem os testes

Comment: Não entendo muito da linguagem ainda mas, pode tentar dar uma lida nesse link: https://realpython.com/blog/python/testing-third-party-apis-with-mock-servers/ No caso eles usaram `GET`

Comment: Estás a usar python3? De flask não percebo muito se tentares fazer um request corre bem? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/ ou com urllib: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request